# oral sex after breaking fast for the day during Ramadan?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, women, ramadan, muslim-practices

Is it permissible to give or receive oral sex after breaking fast for the day during Ramadan?

Answer (score 0):

Given that it's between spouses...

EDIT: Yes, it's permissible to have sexual relations from after sunset to just before sunrise. Just like eating, you can enjoy each other too.

I don't want to get into the debate over whether oral is halaal or haraam. Other brothers and sisters can shed light on this.

Comment: The question says "after breaking fast" ... this implies that it happens at nighttime and not during the fast.

Comment: @UmH Whoops, my mistake :(